# 406 not acceptable for request sent through ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

My controller method accepts both get and post requests.

I am sending most of my parameters as GET URL parameters which work.
I have one multipart file sent as a POST request through ajax which is not working as it should.

I am getting 406/Not Acceptable.

I can't find an error message to explain why it is not acceptable. Please help.

```
    function sendRequest(){
        //GET request
        var url ="/test.html?name="+name+"&sal"+sal;

        //post request
        var inputfl= new FormData();
        inputfl.append("file", $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: '/test.html',
            data: inputfl,
            cache: false,
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

```html
    <input id="file" name="file"/>
```

this is the controller

```
    @RequestMappig(value="/test.html", 
        method{RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST}){
            @ResponseBody

            public List retriveResult(@RequestParam(value="file", required=false) 
            MultipartFile file,
            @RequestParam(value="name", required=false) String name)...{

            sendRequest(name, sal, file);
        }
    )
```